# Какие из приведенных предложений являются безличными?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Вот само задание:
Дан текст, а затем нужно указать, какие предложения безличные.
*Тихо в осеннем лесу. Ничего не слышно, кроме шуршания опавшей листвы под ногами. Приятно оказаться вдруг на знакомой полянке. Как же хорошо здесь проводить время летом! Мне снова хочется летнего тепла.*

(а) Тихо в осеннем лесу.
(б) Ничего не слышно, кроме шуршания опавшей листвы под ногами.
(в) Приятно оказаться вдруг на знакомой полянке.
(г) Как же хорошо здесь проводить время летом!
(д) Мне снова хочется летнего тепла.

На мой взгляд, все 5 предложений являются безличными, но я в этом не уверен (5 правильных ответов из 5 предложенных?), а также еще зачем-то дан текст.
Может ли предложение потерять "безличность" в зависимости от контекста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

**Двусоставное** предложение:

(г) *Как же хорошо здесь **проводить** время летом!*

**проводить время** – инфинитив в роли подлежащего.

(как же) **хорошо**  – составное именное сказуемое.

Здесь **нет состояния человека** в определенный момент времени, это общее суждение.

Comment: Ну кстати да, "хорошо быть высоким" такая же двухвариативная схема. Можно считать личным, можно безличным.

Answer (score 1):

Может ли предложение потерять безличность? Думаю да, если синтаксический разбор можно провести по-разному. Вот несколько подобных примеров:

```
1а Как же хорошо здесь проводить время летом!
1б Хорошо быть высоким.
2 Ветром насыпало много снега
```

Во всех предложениях возможно два варианта сказуемых, и соответственно в одном из вариантов они безличные, а в другом нет